# Minify jQuery based js files

Tags: javascript, css, minify

We are using jQuery in our project. We have numerous custom javascript files in our web-app that have UDFs utilizing the jQuery features. We need to reduce the size (as a part of performance improvement activities) and I am looking for a reliable 'minifier' for these files (it would be great if the same tool could minify the CSS files too)

We tried JSLint and JSMin - but JSLint does not complete and throws many exceptions as soon as it encounters jQuery code.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) is a tool I use, it compresses both JS and CSS well, and it is written in Java (so you can work it into a build process via ant).

Someone's even made an [online version](http://www.refresh-sf.com/yui/) of it.

Comment: The YUI compressor is nice because it uses the Rhino engine to validate that the compression is done correctly.

Comment: I have used YUI Compressor as well and swear by it.  It does a good job and produces working code.  I've used other compressors that only do a static analysis of the code and they break things.  YUI Compressor doesn't just manipulate the text it loads it up in Rhino and knows how to rename things intelligently.

Comment: Wow !! YUI Compressor has all the features I needed. Thanks a lot folks for the help. I have already minified all the JS files and the results look really good.
Thanks all for your help once again.

Comment: Don’t forget to serve your files gzipped as well (if your server isn’t doing that already). I haven’t done a huge amount of minifying and gzipping, but when I was last playing with it, gzipping reduced JS and CSS files to around 33% of the original size. Minifying before gzipping brought them down another 7% or so.

Comment: The online version gives me an OutOfMemoryError and prints a huge stacktrace. And it was only 600k of Javascript. Sad.

Answer (score 4):

There's also [a .NET port of YUI Compressor](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/) which allows you to:-

- intergrate the minification/file combining into Visual Studio post-build events
- intergrate into a TFS Build (including CI)
- if you wish to just use the dll's in your own code (eg. on the fly minification).

because this is a port of the (original) java version YUI Compressor, which a few peeps mention above, it should give you the same results BUT all in the .NET environment -- no need for java.

HTH.

Answer (score 3):

[minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) does the job. There's also [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/), but I've never tried it.

From the minify website:

> Minify is a PHP5 app that can combine
>   multiple CSS or Javascript files,
>   compress their contents (i.e. removal
>   of unnecessary whitespace/comments),
>   and serve the results with HTTP
>   encoding (gzip/deflate) and headers
>   that allow optimal client-side
>   caching. This helps you follow several
>   of Yahoo!'s Rules for High Performance
>   Web Sites.

Answer (score 3):

Try [YUICompress](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) which usually works like a charm. Can minify CSS as well.

Answer (score 0):

A nice one is [Zbugs](http://www.zbugs.com/minify-gzip-compress-css-javascript-online): "Minify and Gzip compress CSS & Javascript in a single click". Type your URL, and you can one-click download the result. It also shows some informations about the size when gziped, minified, concatenated compared with the original.

Answer (score 0):

This is for 2022 users looking for a way to minify Jquery-written JS code. When all other options have been exhausted, I discovered this website that completed the task quickly and flawlessly.

[Minify JavaScript - Online Compressor / Packer](https://www.cleancss.com/javascript-minify/)

Its seems to be built just for the purpose.