# Ajax Design/Refactoring help when rendering new content - like list items and divs

Tags: javascript, ajax, templates, refactoring, duplication

I consistently come across this code smell where I am duplicating markup, and I'm not really sure how to fix it. Here's a typical use case scenario:

Let's say we'd like to post comments to some kind of article. Underneath the article, we see a bunch of comments. These are added with the original page request and are generated by the templating engine (Freemarker in my case, but it can be PHP or whatever).

Now, whenever a user adds a comment, we want to create a new *li* element and inject it in the current page's list of comments. Let's say this *li* contains a bunch of stuff like:

1. The user's avatar
2. Their name
3. A link to click to their profile or send them a private message
4. The text they wrote
5. The date they wrote the comment
6. Some "edit" and "delete" links/buttons if the currently logged in user has permission to do these actions.

Now, all of these things were already written in our template that originally generated the page... so now we have to duplicate it inside of Javascript!

Sure, we can use another templating language - like Jquery's Template plugin - to ease the pain generating and appending this new *li* block... but we still end up with duplicate html markup that is *slightly* different because we can't use macros or other conveniences provided to us by the templating language.

So how do we refactor out the duplication? Is it even possible, or do we just put up with it? What are the best practices being used to solve this problem?

Comment: It's an interesting question and I'm not sure how to answer it, but two things immediately come to mind. For servers implemented in javascript, coffeekup allows the same template to be used both client-side and server-side (not convinced this is a good solution though). Otherwise, you may simply `.clone()` an existing `<li>` and populate with new data. The server-side template can generate a special hidden div for this purpose - I don't feel this is messy, it's signalling: "look, this is meant to be reused!"

Comment: Well, I don't even know what coffeekup is... but I'm using Tomcat, so I doubt that helps ;) .clone() is an interesting alternative. I guess I could hide the template and stuff it at the button of the *ul* element. I'd have to add more id's or classes to every tag if I did that, but that's not a bad solution. It's better than using jquery's templating plugin for this purpose. I'll try it out and see how much of a hassle it is. The one benefit jquery's template has is that it's easy to do - it just duplicates code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem and becomes more obvious as the UI complexity increases, and changes have to be done on both the server and client templates. This problem is fixable by using a the same template markup on both the client and server sides. The template processors must be written in both JavaScript and the server side language.

Two other solutions that are cleaner than the above approach, but both have their own problems:

- Do everything client side
- Do everything server side

If all markup generation is done on the client side, then the server acts more or less like a web service which only sends back data in whatever formats suits the application. JSON, and XML are really popular formats for most web services nowadays. The client always generates the necessary HTML and JS. If going with this approach, the boundary between the client and server must be well defined. Since the client has limited knowledge of what happens on the server, this means that proper error codes must be defined. State management will become harder since most/all server interaction will be happening asynchronously. An example of adding a comment with this approach may look like:

```
$('#add-comment').click(function() {
    var comment = $('#comment-box').text();
    $.ajax('http://example.com/add', {
        success: function() {
            addCommentRow(comment);
        },
        ...
    });
});

function addCommentRow(comment) {
    var user = currentUser().name;

    var html = "<li><b>{user}</b> says {comment}</li>";
    html = html.replace("{user}", user).replace("{comment}", comment);

    var item = $('<li>').html(html);
    $('#comments').append(item);
}
```

The other approach is to do everything server side. Whenever a change happens, shoot a request to the server, and ask it for the updated view. With a fast backend, response times under a second, and proper indicators of network activity, the application should seem very responsive despite everything happening on the server. The above example would be simplified to:

```
$('#add-comment').click(function() {
    $.ajax('http://example.com/add', {
        success: function(response) {
            $('#comments').html(response);
        },
        ...
    });
});
```

Although this seems a lot more cleaner on the client side than the previous approach, we have just moved the markup generation up to the server. However, if the application is not very AJAXy like Google Maps, then this approach may be easier to work with. Again, it's a matter of how complicated the application is, and perhaps maintaining state client side is a necessity for you, in which case you may want to go with the previous approach.

Comment: Thanks for writing the response. The second option could work a bit better. At least that lets me reuse the freemarker template code so I only need to change it in one spot. Right now, I am doing everything client-side and have stuck to sending JSON to the client like your first option, and let me tell you - it's hell. My app is actually very complex, and it's always getting more complex. This isn't sustainable. As for the beginning of your post - what real, practical solution allows to use freemarker on the client side? What platform allows for the same template to used for both?

Comment: Also, is there any place I can read about the advantages/disadvantages for harmonizing the wire protocol (JSON exclusively) vs. sending html fragments? That way I can be aware of the potential problems if I should decide to take option #2. I also want to be consistent as much as possible so I don't have my ajax on the client/server doing it a hundred different ways. I'd like to create some conventions so that each type of ajax call uses the same conventions and patterns. This would greatly simplify things.

Comment: Actually, I don't know if the second option can work actually. What if I need to inspect the result before I render the content? If I pre-render the html, there's not much the javascript can do to avoid adding it if it shouldn't. If I send JSON back, at least I can inspect a variable to see if it should do anything or not. Grrr.. I'm not sure this is going to work either. I'm rather frustrated that something that is so common to do is so needlessly difficult to deal with.

Comment: I gave this a lot of thought as I slept on it... and yuck. I guess doing everything client-side. That's looking like the only real solution. No wonder if you do a "view source" on sites like facebook, it's all just importing javascript files and there's hardly any markup at all...

Comment: @egervari - I don't think there exists a template language that can be shared across the client and server, but writing one isn't that terribly difficult. The template would ideally be HTML with support for conditionals, and repetition, in a language neutral fashion. This might be a good starting point for writing such a template - http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/.If you want to weigh in the benefits and drawbacks of the second approach - read up about AHAH (Asynchronous HTML and HTTP).

Comment: As far as being able to inspect the server response and applying logic before slapping HTML onto the page, you can always return not only HTML, but embedded JavaScript in the response as well. It may sound a little ugly in theory, but its far better than duplicating rendering logic. I asked a similar question a while back and [part of the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468311/how-would-you-organize-a-large-complex-web-application-see-basic-example) concerning AHAH is very applicable to your question.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. AHAH way of doing things might work for a lot of stuff, but now that I think about it, getting tied down to specific html templates is also going to be bad for this application too. I honestly think I need to move everything to client, as sad as that is. Man, I got a lot of work ahead of me. Thanks for the help