# How does Stack Overflow implement the character counter saying xyz characters left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

How does Stack Overflow do the character counter saying xyz characters left?

[image]

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/NHyLC/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/6XnaT/ and a related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468311/how-would-you-organize-a-large-complex-web-application-see-basic-example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably something like (with jQuery):

```
$('#txtbox').keypress(function() {
    var max = 500;
    var textLen = $(this).val().length;
    var textLeft = max - textLen;
    $('#charCount').text(
        textLeft + ' character' + (textLeft == 1 ? '' : 's') + ' left'
    );
});
```

(I know it's lazy to not actually look and see how they do it, but here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/FishBasketGordo/hqex8/)

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<textarea id="text" onkeyup="charCount(this);"></textarea>
<span id="chars"></span>
```

JS:

```
var maxChars = 500;
function charCount(el) {
   document.getElementById('chars').innerText = maxChars - this.value.length;
}
```

not tested, but that's the basics.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: I'm 1 hour away from holidays, so I'm too lazy to try and rummage around my brain for the proper cross-browser version.

Comment: I'd use `.innerHTML` since it's a digit. Happy holidays!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done several ways but here is a link to some simple source code.  The only for sure way to know how SO does it is to look into there compressed javascript.

http://javascript.internet.com/forms/character-counter.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this page on one of my sites http://www.bestvaluesolicitors.com/contact-us

Peek at the JS - you are looking for this function:

`function ml(id,max,repeat){if($F(id).length>max){$(id).value=$F(id).substring(0,max);}$(id).next('div').update($F(id).length+' / '+max+' characters');if(repeat==true){setTimeout('ml("'+id+'",'+max+','+repeat+')',500);}}`

Esentially it is a combination of a timer and counting the length of text in the `textarea`

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

var max = 1000;

```
document.getElementById('freddy').onkeypress =
document.getElementById('freddy').onkeyup = 
document.getElementById('freddy').onkeydown = function(){
    var count = this.value.length;
    if(max < count){
        this.value = this.value.substring(0,999);
        return false;
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('susan').innerHTML =
          (max-count)+' characters left!';
    },1);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/S4Dtu/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the definition of StackExchange's charCounter() method. It's a little obfuscated, but you can find the logic if you dig through it:

```
charCounter: function(c) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var d = $(this).parents("form").find("span.text-counter");
        var e = this;
        var f = function() {
            var j = c.min;
            var l = c.max;
            var k = c.setIsValid || function() {};
            var h = e.value ? e.value.length : 0;
            var i = h > l * .8 ? "supernova" : h > l * .6 ? "hot" : h > l * .4 ? "warm" : "cool";
            var g = "";
            if (h == 0) {
                g = "enter at least " + j + " characters";
                k(false);
            } else {
                if (h < j) {
                    g = j - h + " more to go..";
                    k(false);
                } else {
                    g = l - h + " character" + (l - h != 1 ? "s" : "") + " left";
                    k(h <= l);
                }
            }
            d.text(g);
            if (!d.hasClass(i)) {
                d.removeClass("supernova hot warm cool").addClass(i);
            }
        };
        $(this).bind("blur focus keyup", a.DelayedReaction(f, 100, {
            sliding: true
        }).trigger);
    });
}
```

And the comment text areas, for example, are set up like so (again, obfuscated):

```
var x = z.find("textarea");
x.charCounter({
    min: 15,
    max: 600,
    setIsValid: A
});
```