# How important is using tiny variable names in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, optimization, minify

It seems like, for many javascript widgets, the authors have made a conscious effort to use tiny variable names. For example:

```
// Instead of...
this.mousePositions = new Array();
// they use...
this.mp = new Array();
```

My question is this: how important is this in terms of reducing overall javascript file request size? I'm working on releasing a javascript widget to the public, which, after being minified, is about 2.8KB. However, because the main advantage of this plugin is how lightweight it is, does anyone have experience with whether it's worth it to go through and switch out all of the sensical variable names that I used with these new, tiny variable names? It just seems like the code is so much less readable that way and it's going to be much harder to maintain.

Thanks for your help!

Charlie

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How important? not *really* unless they're used all over the place, [delivering your scripts via gzip compression](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/payload.html#GzipCompression) negates most of the name byte-cost there.

But why not have the best of both words?  Use **descriptive** names when developing (why punish yourself?), [then minify your scripts](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/payload.html#MinifyJS) as part of the build process to get small compact names for production code, and a minimal-size transfer to the user.

Comment: Great! This helps a ton. It's also very much a relief to know that I can get the benefits without the pain in the butt variable names.

Comment: Worth pointing out that different minifiers behave... differently. For example YUI compressor is conservative and will not minify the names of object properties (`thing.mouseposition` => `a.a`) just in case it is accessed dynamically elsewhere in your code (`var foo='mouseposition'; /* ... much code ... */ var pos = thing[foo]`). Google's Closure goes further and will minify names like this but requires more configuration to help when linking multiple source files together where property names cannot be minified without breaking dependent code in other modules.

Answer (score 4):

Many times, the author will write the longer form, for readability, and then have a program like Google's [Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/), or [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) to shorten it, for faster transfer to the client.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the links - I'll take a look at those.

Answer (score 3):

A good minifier will shorten variable names. You should keep a readable copy of the source code with good variable names and white space. Then you should minify it for use on production. The original copy will be used for further development and debugging. You should use a good naming scheme for this process. Example: Create `my_program_v1.js` then run it through a minifier like [Google's Closure compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) and name the result `my_program_v1.min.js` and serve that version on the Web.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter at all. Really, the only advantage is to *prevent* people from knowing how your code works. If it's okay with you for it to be readable then the size of the variable names is irrelevant. IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You could develop your scripts using the longer, more descriptive names for your variables and then minify your script file for production release.  This way you have something very readable for development and something small (relatively) and compressed to send to the clients.

There are a lot of minification tools out there.

[Minify jQuery based js files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841253/javascript-good-tool-to-minify-jquery-based-js-files)