# Is my work flow correct in BootStrap (reference to using css and min.css)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

can I confirm that it is good practice to develop a bootstrap site using the bootstrap.css file and then when ready for showtime I then switch out bootstrap.css for the minified version?

Seems simple enough, but what happens if I edit the bootstrap.css - can I then compress the bootstrap using any compression method or is it better to edit the min.css in the first instance?

Thanks for all replies...

Answer (score 0):

The workflow is correct, use the development version for development and replace with the minified version upon release.  I would recommend implementing any changes by subclassing the appropriate styles or using CSS precedence to apply your style instead of Bootstraps.  These modifications can be made outside the bootstrap.css file  If you cannot override a style due to precedence, modify the bootstrap file to fix your issues and minify using one of the many minifiers that exist which can be included as part of your build.

Only modify the bootstrap.css file if absolutely necessary, since your changes will not be included in any updates to the framework.  This will make updating your bootstrap version more work intensive.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply - what about simply re-minifying once changes have been made? Is that another way?

Answer (score 0):

Although the best workflow would be to implement your CSS modifications separately than bootstrap.css file (as stated by Kevin), if you really want to do so, there are some good answers about minifier tools you can easily find to shrink your modified bootstrap.css

https://stackoverflow.com/a/841272/1591720